# How can I create a 'global streamwriter' in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Can someone please tell how make a global `Streamwriter`?

My code :

```
try
{
    // Try to create the StreamWriter
    StreamWriter File1 = new StreamWriter(newPath);
}
catch (IOException)
{
    /* Catch System.IO.IOException was unhandled
       Message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Dilan V 8
       Desktop\TextFile1.txt' because it is being used by another process.
    */
    File1.Write(textBox1.Text);
    File1.Close();
    throw;
}
```

The error I'm getting `The name 'File1' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By moving the declaration of the variable outside the try/catch you would make it exist both inside the scope (context) of the try and the catch.

However I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish as the only way you will in this case come into the catch is if you fail to try to open the file, and in that case you cannot write to it in the catch

```
StreamWriter file1 = null; // declare outside try/catch
try
{
    file1 = new StreamWriter(newPath);
}
catch (IOException)
{
    if(file1 != null){
       file1.Write(textBox1.Text);
       file1.Close();
    }
    throw;
}
```

Moving the variable so that it is declared before the try catch does not however make it global, it simply makes it so it exists through the entire scope of the remaining code in that method you are in.

If you want to create a global variable inside a class you would do something like this

```
public class MyClass{
   public string _ClassGlobalVariable;

   public void MethodToWorkIn(){
       // this method knows about _ClassGlobalVariable and can work with it
       _ClassGlobalVariable = "a string";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# things are declared within a scope and only available within that scope

You declare your variable File1 within the try scope, while it's initialisation is well placed (it could throw an exception), what you want is to declare it beforehand so that in the outer scope (in which both the try and catch are) so that it is available to both.

```
StreamWriter File1 = null;
try
{
    // Try to create the StreamWriter
    File1 = new StreamWriter(newPath);
}
catch (IOException)
{
    /* Catch System.IO.IOException was unhandled
       Message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Dilan V 8
    */ Desktop\TextFile1.txt' because it is being used by another process.

    File1.Write(textBox1.Text);
    File1.Close();
    throw;
}
```

However this still is a wrong approach as the only thing you do within your try is to instantiate a new StreamWriter. If you end up in the catch, it means this failed, if it failed you shouldn't touch the object anymore as it wasn't properly constructed (you don't write to it nor close it, you cannot write to it at all, it didn't work).

Basically what you're doing in your code is saying "try to start up the car engine, if it failed, start hitting the Accelerator anyway".